# how to create two sections, one with an full screen image an another with the rest of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page with two sections.
The first section will populate the entire screen with an image as a background, and the second, that the user can either scroll to or click a button to be scrolled to, has the text
something like the following image (that shows the two pages one after the other)[image]
or like the [dropbox website](https://www.dropbox.com/)

my current code is, but this does not work

```
  <section  Style="margin-top:0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000008;
    background-image: url(/assets/highway4.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1500px"></section>
<section>
the login form code
</section>
```

I also read this [post](http://www.minimit.com/articles/code-tips/perfect-responsive-fullscreen-backgrounds) but it did not work.
By did not work I mean: that at the moment I am forcing height and width with pixels, this won't look the same on all computer screens. So I am trying to make it scale the section to take a full screen for every screen size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the picture and the form on a full screen, you must first give

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then you can give the image maybe `height: 90%` and reserve the rest for the form

```
.top-image {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1500/1000);
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RfYY3/)

If you want a full screen image, give `height: 100%` to the `div`.